# Limit / Clean Redis Keys

Tags: redis

I'm currently wirting keys from multiple servers to redis which logstash is picking up.
However those which aren't picked up are lying around until i delete them manually.
This can happen due to misconfig or malicious executions. Due to the fact that those keys are actively written, the TTL doesn't work for me.

Is there any way redis supports a "limit" which keys are allowed to be created, or is lua scipting efficient getting all keys except some defined ones and deleting them?

Working with redis 3.2 (RHEL 7); potential to go up to v. 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this can be done with ACLs by specifying which keys are allowed to be written by a user:
https://redis.io/topics/acl

Afaik this is available from redis version 6, so i have to build it for Rhel7.